# Parse a JSON and use it in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, json

Can you help me to parse a JSON file in a array so that I can iterate over it and display the contents on my lightning component?

Getting the JSON response from here: https://api.airbnb.com/v2/search_results?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty&location=dublin

Now I need to show the listings object as a list on the component using aura:iteration attribute.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any function to deserialize an JSON to an array in lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160846/is-there-any-function-to-deserialize-an-json-to-an-array-in-lightning-component)

Comment: @glls The answer for this was basically the question for the other, so they're complimentary questions, not duplicates.

Comment: @sfdcfox, good to know, too bad there is no flag for sames answer as.. (or is there?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean on the client side, then its just:

```
var json = ...;

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
var results = parsed.search_results;
component.set("v.listings", results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess before parse once go stringify then parse like.

```
var obj;
var jsonString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
// Now you getting the parse format json.
component.set('v.returnData', jsonString);
```